# Persistent values in ListBox in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

This is my first question in this forum and I am very new to Excel VBA.

I have a text box that has an `Exit` event. My requirement is that when I fill that textbox and exit from there its values should be populated in ListBox. Now, when I am trying to insert the value again inside textbox, it overwrites previous value inside the ListBox. I want the values to be persistent. So the values entered in text box should come in sequence.

Here is what I tried :

```
ListBox1.ColumnCount = 2 

ListBox1.AddItem 
ListBox1.List(0) = TextBox2.Text
```

But then how can I take the next value from Text box and make it visible in List box...(so if I enter 3 values in text box it should show three rows in Listbox)

Comment: that's it? maybe give us something to work with ? your code attempt ? nothing ?

Comment: Sure. Here is what I tried :
ListBox1.ColumnCount = 2
ListBox1.AddItem
ListBox1.List(0) = TextBox2.Text

But then how can I take the next value from Text box and make it visible in List box...(so if I enter 3 values in text box it should show three rows in Listbox)

Comment: @abhishek could you post the code in your question

Answer (score 4):

When you say `ListBox1.List(0) = TextBox2.Text`, you are telling the code to always add (replace on 2nd instance) to the first item in the listbox.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ListBox1.ColumnCount = 2
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    ListBox1.AddItem
    ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 0) = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

If you do not need a multi column listbox then the below will also do.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    ListBox1.AddItem TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```